# Typescript - Why implementation of the interface is not forced accordingly

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm wondering why implementing twice same generic interface but with different parameters doesn't enforce the correct signatures in the derived class. The type of the generic parameter is omitted.

Please see sample:

```
interface IEvent { id: number; }
interface IHandle<T> {
  handle(event: T): void;
}

class EmailSentEvent implements IEvent {
  constructor(public id: number, public address: string) {}
}

class UserRegisteredEvent implements IEvent {
  constructor(public id: number) {}
}

class MailHandlerState implements 
  IHandle<EmailSentEvent>, 
  IHandle<UserRegisteredEvent> 
{
  // One implementation is enough to satisfy both interfaces
  handle = (event: EmailSentEvent): void => {

  };
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-water-mnly7?file=/src/index.ts)

Is there a way to enforce the implementation of both generic parameters? Thank you!

Comment: Seems like a bug in the TypeScript compiler. I believe it should require `handle` to have type `(event: EmailSentEvent | UserRegisteredEvent): void`

Comment: Looks like problem is even bigger and strict function types are not applied when checking type compatibility of object props. `const h: IHandle<UserRegisteredEvent> = { handle(e: EmailSentEvent) { e.address.toString() } };` will blow up at runtime. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAk4gCYBsIA8AKgHzIDeAUMsgBZZ4QAUEAbhOAFzJECU3rAPbBsAbkoBfSpTABPAA4oAogFs4wXAGUOYJe3DIAvBWQjuIAK4qARtAA0yONmxQIAZzfc3YKKADmyBLicorIAKpu0ABKEH7A3tAQ2Ho6RiZmyJY20IHilAiCIN503BgM+AQR0bHxkK7J+mBkxuR05cwQ3KrqWjop4LwmEAB0Ti7ubsNggpo+-kyDErmUtMP0OPhMrRkAjIG84kA)

Comment: This is super weird, but changing to `handle: (event: T) => void;` in interface works as expected. [Try](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFEBuFzIN7LAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANzIC+AUKJLIiqgBJwhEANhAA8AFQB8+FsmQALfkIhkAFBGzgyYgJTIAvFMwB7YvRasWCQXADON5OipxgggMo4wWD4SoAHYVQe9hgaYNKyCEYgNmBQFAhgRlAqvhQ0gsAIhKTk1HRQADTIqemZyHBERFAQdmQxUKAA5rp4rBZWtvYAqjbQAEoQjcAx0BBEXrjAfgFBaBNheDLIkdGx8YnJJRlZxGSUtNAtbSyW1nbIALLOgnwCwlCuYHCQPv4QgeD2S7yKwiKO13c4HmEiK31uShEPX6g2GHDGIOQLEWsgA9KjyEYAO7IaBQJI2JYKO4oPTINShMgAlxAzyhbRkYzEfRSRZLJhmJhAA)

Comment: @AlekseyL. Very nice observation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:**

To make this work, change **method** notation

```
interface IHandle<T> {
    handle(event: T): void;
}
```

to **property with a function type**

```
interface IHandle<T> {
    handle: (event: T) => void;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFEBuFzIN7LAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANzIC+AUKJLIiqgBJwhEANhAA8AFQB8+FsmQALfkIhkAFBGzgyYgJTIAvFMwB7YvRasWCQXADON5OipxgggMo4wWD4SoAHYVQe9hgaYNKyCEYgNmBQFAhgRlAqvhQ0gsAIhKTk1HRQADTIqemZyHBERFAQdmQxUKAA5rp4rBZWtvYAqjbQAEoQjcAx0BBEXrjAfgFBaBNheDLIkdGx8YnJJRlZxGSUtNAtbSyW1nbIALLOgnwCwlCuYHCQPv4QgeD2S7yKwiKO13c4HmEiK31uShEPX6g2GHDGIOQLEWsgA9KjyEYAO7IaBQJI2JYKO4oPTINShMgAlxAzyhbRkYzEfRSRZLJhmJhAA)

** In this specific case implementation can still use method syntax

---

Turns out this works as intended:

> `--strictFunctionTypes` mode in which function type parameter positions are checked contravariantly instead of bivariantly. The stricter checking applies to all function types, **except those originating in method or construcor declarations**. Methods are excluded specifically to ensure generic classes and interfaces (such as Array) continue to mostly relate covariantly. The impact of strictly checking methods would be a much bigger breaking change as a large number of generic types would become invariant (even so, we may continue to explore this stricter mode)

[Source](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654)

Also in [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types)

Comment: Interesting! And even though you declare it that way, you don't have to *implement* it that way, you can use method syntax in the classes. Nice!

Comment: Wow thats quite some interesting details embedded there!

Comment: [Method syntax example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFEBuFzIN7LAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANzIC+AUKJLIiqgBJwhEANhAA8AFQB8+FslnIAFvyEQyACgjZwZMQEpkAXimYA9sXotWLBILgBnW8nRU4wQQGUcYLJ8JUADsJUng4YmmDScsgIxiC2YFAUCGDGUKp+FDSCwAiEpOTUdFAANMjpmdnIcEREUBD2ZHFQoADmenisltZ2DgCqttAAShDNwHHQEETeuMD+gcFoU+F4MnLRsfGJyallWTnEZJS00G0dLFY29sgAsi6CfALCUG5gcJC+ARBB4A4rvErCIictw84EWEhKv3uyhEfUGw1GHAmYOQLGWkUUDwg6jCZCBrhBXjCOjIJjMK1kGOU2M8ZFhUCGIzGtUmRJJpiI5nR-yxGhpjmc+M8i2QAB9kHSGQjxizPMTkKSiBFInIAPQq5AAOi15OYFiAA)

Comment: Damn feel bad that it enforces a catchall function `(event: EmailSentEvent | UserRegisteredEvent)` which would have to pattern-match for achieving a `function per typeof T`. But i'm happy the compiler at least forces some type safe way of doing it :)). I guess the compiler could be smart and map in a dictionary<TType, Action<T>> when turning it into plain JS whilst still allowing multiple methods/propertyfunctions with same name. Thanks a lot both @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @CristianE. this is regular overloads syntax in typescript. Making smart map is not trivial because types do not make it to runtime (erased at compile time)